# Restrict S3 permissions to just website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have people uploading video content and I'd like to restrict the video content to ONLY be streamed from my site. Since the video URLs in the video tag are easily accessible through the HTML source, I was to stop people from copying the direct s3 url and putting it in another tab.

I was looking over the docs here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/AccessPolicyLanguage_ElementDescriptions.html#Condition

But it wasn't immediately obvious to me.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make this bucket private and use the signed URL to give access only to your users on your website. Signed URLs have short life (and required policy baked into it) when you generate them. This will prevent misuse even if somebody steals the URLs (or sends you the faked referrer headers etc).

You can create these URLs manually (difficult to manage) or programmatically (some coding work required). In the second case, once your website user contacts your server, then generate and serve the auto-expiring URL. Use this URL then on your website.

[Overview of Signed URLs - Amazon CloudFront](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls-overview.html).